# What's the meaning about characterEncoding

Tags: javascript, regex, sizzle

I'm reading the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com) source code. I'm confused when I read the regular about characterEncoding. In the source code, the characterEncoding defined as below:

```
characterEncoding = "(?:\\\\.|[\\w-]|[^\\x00-\\xa0])+"
```

It looks try to match \\. or \w- or ^\x00-\xa0.
I know [\w-] means \ or w or -, and I also know [^\x00-\xa0] means anything not in \x00-\x20. Who can tell me what's the meaning about \\. and \x00-\x20.

Thanks

---

I think I know what it is. The type of characterEncoding is string. So if we assign like below:

```
characterEncoding = "(?:\\\\.|[\\w-]|[^\\x00-\\xa0])+"
```

The value of characterEncoding is:

```
(?:\\.|[\w-]|[^\x00-\xa0])+
```

So if I build a regular expression like above, it means:

```
[\w-] // A symbol of Latin alphabet or a digit or an underscore '_' or '-'
[^\\x00-\\xa0] // ISO 10646 characters U+00A1 and higher
\\. // '\' and '.'
```

So this time, my question is when will the pattern `\\.` work?

Answer (score 4):

The variable would be better named `css3Identifier` or something.

Transforming `[\w-]|[^\x00-\xa0]` into an equivalent form that matches the spec better:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_-]|[\u00A1-\uFFFF]
```

Consider that `A1` is `161`, `_` is underscore and `-` is a dash and then
[read this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters):

> In CSS3, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors (see [SELECT] [or is this still true])) can contain only the characters **[A-Za-z0-9]** and ISO 10646 characters **161 and higher**, plus the **hyphen (-)** and the **underscore (_)**

"and higher" is covered by `-\uFFFF`

---

The `"\\\\."` matches any single character preceded by backslash. e.g.- `\7B` would match `\7` and then `B` would be caught
by the middle alternative. It also matches `\n`, `\r`, `\t` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the valid regex format of CSS identifier, class, tag and attributes. A link is also in the source code comment. Following are the rules, including the possible use of backslashes which might answer your question:

> 4.1. Characters and case
>
> The following rules always hold:
>
> - All CSS style sheets are case-insensitive, except for parts that are not under the control of CSS. For example, the case-sensitivity of values of the HTML attributes "id" and "class", of font names, and of URIs lies outside the scope of this specification. Note in particular that element names are case-insensitive in HTML, but case-sensitive in XML.
> - In CSS3, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors (see [SELECT] [or is this still true])) can contain only the characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters 161 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit or a hyphen followed by a digit. They can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F". (See [UNICODE310] and [ISO10646].)
> - In CSS3, a backslash () character indicates three types of character escapes.
>
>   First, inside a string (see [CSS3VAL]), a backslash followed by a newline is ignored (i.e., the string is deemed not to contain either the backslash or the newline).
>
>   Second, it cancels the meaning of special CSS characters. Any character (except a hexadecimal digit) can be escaped with a backslash to remove its special meaning. For example, "\"" is a string consisting of one double quote. Style sheet preprocessors must not remove these backslashes from a style sheet since that would change the style sheet's meaning.
>
>   Third, backslash escapes allow authors to refer to characters they can't easily put in a style sheet. In this case, the backslash is followed by at most six hexadecimal digits (0..9A..F), which stand for the ISO 10646 ([ISO10646]) character with that number. If a digit or letter follows the hexadecimal number, the end of the number needs to be made clear. There are two ways to do that:
>
>   1. with a space (or other whitespace character): "\26 B" ("&B"). In this case, user agents should treat a "CR/LF" pair (13/10) as a single whitespace character.
>   2. by providing exactly 6 hexadecimal digits: "\000026B" ("&B")
>
>   In fact, these two methods may be combined. Only one whitespace character is ignored after a hexadecimal escape. Note that this means that a "real" space after the escape sequence must itself either be escaped or doubled.
> - Backslash escapes are always considered to be part of an identifier or a string (i.e., "\7B" is not punctuation, even though "{" is, and "\32" is allowed at the start of a class name, even though "2" is not).

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters